# Centos 6 MOD_REWRITE not working

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I'm losing my mind. I've literally tried every suggestion on these boards I could find.

I have a simple URL:

```
www.somedomain.com/!/profile.php?id=1234567
```

I have this in the .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  Options +FollowSymlinks
  RewriteEngine On
   RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)(/?)$ profile.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

I don't understand why it's not rewriting to `somedomain.com/!/1234567`.

Comment: ... Is it in the `!/` directory?

Comment: yes profile.php is in !/

Answer (score 0):

To do exactly what you want in your question i.e in a .htacess file in the /!/ directory would require the following

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=([0-9]+)$
RewriteRule ^[a-zA-Z0-9]+[.]php$ %1 [L]
```

If you can, its better not to use .htaccess files since it impacts performance. You can place something in the VirtualHost as follows:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=([0-9]+)$
RewriteRule ^/!/[a-zA-Z0-9]+[.]php$ %1 [L]
```

or if you want to do something with the filename and path:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=([0-9]+)$
RewriteRule ^(/!/[a-zA-Z0-9]+)[.]php$ $0/%1 [L]
```